# Social Skils for Militia Captains?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What social skills are important to militia captains?  The ones I think might be, but have no way of confirming are:

- Leadership
- Organization
- Teacher

Are these used by militia captains?  If not, are any social skills at all?

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't social skills, they're used in military training, or (in the case of organization) used by an appointed manager.

None of the social skills (such as comedian, liar, flatterer, etc.) have any bearing on military ability, except in cases where an increase in those social skills result in a physical attribute increase.

So what *do* Teacher and Student do? Teacher's lead better demonstrations (so more skill ups, faster) and Student's learn better from demonstrations (again, more skill ups, faster).

Comment: Does leadership do anything?  Militia Captains do seem to gain experience in it.

Comment: @C. Ross - according to the wiki, "Toady One stated in a Fortress talk that it is used when a dwarf tries to teach another dwarf a skill through a lecture. "